# Association involving multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a data structure similar to the following picture.

Table A has_many Table C through Table B; and

Table C has_many Table E through Table D

In order to make Table A has an association to Table E so that I can do a `object_a.has_many_object_e`, and having to meet the restrictions below:

1. Adding foreign keys to any table is not allowed
2. Relationship needs to be bi-directional

What can I do to implement this?

Thanks !!

[alt text http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/763/railsassociation.gif](http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/763/railsassociation.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`nested_has_many_through`](http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through) plugin which will allow you to do:

```
class ModelA
  has_many :model_bs
  has_many :model_cs, :through => :modelbs
  has_many :model_es, :through => :modelcs
end

class ModelB
  belongs_to :model_as
  belongs_to :model_cs
end

class ModelC
  has_many :model_bs
  has_many :model_ds
  has_many :model_as, :through => :modelbs
  has_many :model_es, :through => :modelcs
end
```

etc.